# How to toggle between a still image and a gif from giphy api on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, gif, giphy-api

I am trying to load a still image into the variable topicImage and then switch to the animated GIF when clicked.  My code causes the image to disappear when clicked instead of switching to the animated GIF. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
            var topicImage = $("<img>");
            topicImage.attr("src", results[i].images.fixed_height_still.url);

            topicImage.on( "click", function() {
              topicImage.attr("src", results[i].images.fixed_height.url);
            });



            gifDiv.prepend(p);
            gifDiv.prepend(topicImage);

            $("#addedGifs").prepend(gifDiv);
          }
        });
            console.log(searchParam);
    });
```

Comment: Does the GIF eventually show up?  A common trick is to place a hidden `<img>` on the page that references the same image.  Then when you switch to the image, the browser has already retrieved the image and has it cached.

Comment: Also have you verified that `results[i].images.fixed_height.url` contains accurate values?

Comment: It shows up and the values seem fine.  Each one works if they are done separately.  It just won't switch for some reason.  Does anyone know the syntax to switch between two src  attributes on click?

Comment: Here is the error I get in the console.
gifTastic.html:90 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (gifTastic.html:90)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)